# Check if this is last line in file

Tags: python, logging

I'm currently working on a log script with time,value entries.

I use the script as follows:

```
./parsy.py < log
```

and in the script I loop over the lines with

```
for line in sys.stdin:
```

Is there an easy way to check if the current line is the last one of the input, because I have the save the time of this line as the total time the log ran.

I could update this total time every line, but that's not that efficient...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't you do it *after* the loop runs to completion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If extracting the time is as expensive as you say, you could do something like:

```
line = None
for line in sys.stdin:
  # ...
if line is not None:
  # `line' contains the last line; extract the time etc
```

Comment: Offcourse... After the loop, the line variable still contains the last line of the file... Thanks!